# Is devise a full engine or a mountable engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've been looking at Devise's source code and can't seem to figure this out. Is it a full engine or a mountable one?

It doesn't seem to be using `isolate_namespace`.

Comment: Have you ever found an answer outside of StackOverflow?